# Point AWS ELB to Heroku DNS target

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-route53

I’m migrating our services to AWS(web, services and DB). All our services are running on Heroku. To minimize the downtime we would like to update CNAME record of our subdomain to point it to AWS ELB(our domain is registered with GoDaddy). ELB is suppose to route the traffic to Heroku DNS target(until we sync the data).

is it possible to route the traffic ELB through Heroku DNS target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. ELB can route traffic only to

1. targets specified by instance id
2. targets specified by ip address (can't be publicly routable ip address)
3. lambda functions

That is it and there is unfortunately not much to add to this.

Comment: I can think of one thing to add... if the service exclusively handles requests and responses within the [limits of ALB/Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html) (1 MB body size, max, either direction) then a Lambda function could be written to proxy requests from the ALB to Heroku with standard https requests.

Comment: Sure, and in the same way you can set up EC2 instance to proxy the request. What I meant is that the is no direct way to to use ELB for this.

Comment: You are correct, it's not *directly* possible.  But sometimes outside-the-box suggestions are not obvious to everyone (OP didn't mention the option of proxying) and are more valuable than the simple correct answer.

Comment: @MatusDubrava is it possible to point one subdomain(aa.example.com) to another subdomain (bb.example.com) and create A record in bb.example.com to point it to Heroku DNS target? (Assume aa.example.com on GoDaddy, bb.example.com on Route53)

Comment: That is not possible. If you want to use Route53, you need to create public hosted zone for a whole domain (not subdomain), and then you need to make sure that Route53 is responsible for resolution of that domain. This can be done by either migrating your domain from GoDaddy to Route53 or by updating Name Server values at the GoDaddy side to use AWS Name Servers. Once Route53 is resolving your domain, you can create CNAME record to point aa.example.com to bb.example.com and then create another CNAME record to point bb.example.com to Heroku target.

Comment: But since you are just pointing A -> B -> C, you can skip the middle part and simply point A -> C (aa.example.com -> Heroku target). About that A record, 
 you can use it instead of CNAME but you would need to know IP address of your target and since IP addresses can easily change, I would still recommend using CNAME record.

Comment: @MatusDubrava sorry for the confusion. All the domains and subdomains are hosted on GoDaddy.

Parent domain is hosted onGoDaddy www.example.com (has aa.example.com and bb.example.com hosted on GoDaddy)
aa.expmple.com -> pointed to Heroku
bb.example.com -> pointed to AWS.

In order to minimize the downtime. We are thinking to update aa.example.com  -> bb.expmple.com CNAME record on GoDaddy(and bb subdomain on Route53 with a A record to point it to Heroku). Once the migration is done remove the A (Heroku) record and add A record for ELB. 
is that doable?

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by `bb subdomain on Route53`. You can't have both GoDaddy and Route53 resolving your domain at the same time. You can create A, CNAME, ... records either on one side or the other but what you are trying to achieve seems doable. Just be aware of the fact that ELB is highly available, meaning that there are more nodes that are scaling up and down based on the traffic, which means that using A record to point to ELB is a bad idea (IP addresses change constantly). You will need to use CNAME, or more preferably, ALIAS A record (but this is unique to Route53).